# Como instalar compiladores C++ e bibliotecas de versões anteriores no visual studio 2015?

Tags: c, c++, visual-studio, compiladores

Como posso instalar versões antigas de compiladores e bibliotecas de c++ no visual studio 2015, sem ter que instalar o IDE junto? (ou seja, somente o necessário para compilar, executar e debugar as aplicações).
Gostaria de deixá-lo assim:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Mas não consigo. Baixei SDK da versão do VS 2008 e 2010. O SDK da 2008 instalou perfeitamente, mas não apareceu na lista. Enquanto o da 2010 está bloqueando, pois diz que necessita do .NET Framework 4 para instalar os compiladores, mas sempre que tento instalar, diz que já existe uma versão instalada no sistema (Windows 7 (32 bits)). :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua pergunta não é idiota amigo, estamos nessa comunidade para ajudar uns aos outros, agora vamos a sua pergunta.

Segundo alguns foruns do MSDN, o visual studio 2015, esta com problemas de compatibilidade com versões mais antigas, tanto no upgrade quanto no down, alguns devs não estão nem dando update por causa disso.

Mas acho que este poste pode lhe ajudar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32695909/downgrade-c-compiler-specefications

Lembrando que você tem que ter o VS do downgrade instalado.